Can someone explain what exactly line 10 is doing? "reverse(s.begin()+j, s.begin()+i);"
This is a leetcode problem where we have to reverse the strings. here is the link to the problem. Reverse Words In A String.
here is the snippet of code i want to understand:
class Solution {
public:
    string reverseWords(string s) {
        int n=s.length();
        reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
        s.push_back(' ');
        int j=0;
        for(int i=0; i<=n; i++){
            if(s[i]==' '){
                reverse(s.begin()+j, s.begin()+i);
                j=i+1;
            }
        }
        s.pop_back();
        return s;
    }
};


Recommendation: State what you think the line is doing and your reasoning. If you're right, the answer's easy, but if you aren't, answers can address where your reasoning goes astray. Right now your question is too simplistic, and the answer is equally simplistic:  "Yes, someone can explain exactly what line 10 is doing."

Another thing is to step through the code with your debugger.  That way you can go line by line and see how the program flows and what happens.

When you asked this question on the LeetCode forums, what answers did you get there?

Well if you have questions like that, being able to read and find online documentation about C++ is invaluable. Most of us use the site cppreference.com for that e.g. see std::reverse

Also note competitive coding is not a good way to learn a language. So it seems you skipped that part e.g. visit learncpp.com first. Last side note learn to use longer variable names (the compiler doesn't care) and it will make your code more readable.

The line reverse(s.begin() + j, s.begin() + i) flips the characters in part of the string between positions j and i. For example, if the string is "dlrow olleh " and we are reversing from j = 0 to i = 5, it will reverse the first word "dlrow" into "world". It does this by swapping the first and last letters, then the next pair of letters, and so on, until the whole word is flipped. After this, the word "dlrow" becomes "world" while the rest of the string stays the same.

reverse(s.begin()+j, s.begin()+i);

Reverses the characters between s[j] through s[i], not including the last character. So practically speaking, it reverses the chars between s[j] and s[i-1].  Or more precisely, it reverses the substring starting at s[j] and of length i-j
Example:
 std::string s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
 std::reverse(s.begin()+3, s.begin()+5);
 std::cout << s << std::endl;

prints:
ABCEDFGHIJKLMNOP
OP's entire reverseWords function is the classic "reverse the individual words in a string" problem.  Reverses the entire string first. Then re-reverses each individual word.  Each time a space char is found after the whole string reversal, that index becomes i. The substring of length i-j starting at s[j] is reversed. Then j is incremented to i+1 and the loop continues.
